# Explicit generators of maximal ideals in completed Hecke algebras

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, hecke-algebras

A particular question:

Let M be the subset of Z/3[[x]] consisting of those power series that are reductions of elements of Z[[x]] that arise as expansions of modular forms for Gamma_0 (2). (Explicitly, M is Z/3[E] where E is the reduction of the expansion of the normalized weight 2 Eisenstein series.)

The Hecke operators T_n with (n,6)=1 act on M through their action on modular forms (the action doesn't depend on the weight); let HE be the algebra of endomorphisms of the group M
spanned by these T_n. The annihilator of E in HE is a maximal ideal m generated by the T_p with p=5 mod 6 and the (T_p)+I, p=1 mod 6.(I believe that representation theory which connects newforms with Galois representations shows that m is the only maximal ideal in HE that is the annihilator of a non-zero element of M).

Let O be the m-completion of HE. I believe that representation theory shows that O is (Noetherian) local. So mO is finitely generated

QUESTION--Can one write down a small finite set of generators of mO explicitly?

MOTIVATION--Let F be the reduction of the weight 12 cusp form delta and G be F(x^2). Let M_0
be the Z/2[G] submodule of M generated by 1 and F. There is a great deal of evidence that
HE stabilizes M_0. An answer to the question above would let me settle this.

MORE GENERALLY--Working in Z/ell [[x]] with ell=2 or 3, one can ask analogous questions with
Gamma_0 (2) replaced by Gamma_0 (N) with (N,ell)=1. Now m is not necessarily unique, but I 
believe only finitely many m can occur. Can one write down elements of M that these m are the annihilators of explicitly? Can one write down finite sets of generators of the corresponding mO explicitly? Again this would allow me to settle questions analogous to those posed in the motivation.

EDIT(5/7/15)--A PARTICULAR SPECIAL CASE

The above question hasn't perhaps been particular enough to elicit any answers. Here's a special case of it, prompted by question 204722, "Mod 2 modular forms in levels 5 and 25 ...", that I hope will do better.

Let M be an odd prime and P be the subspace of Z/2[[x]] consisting of mod 2 modular forms f for Gamma_0 (M^2) with U_2(f)=U_M(f)=0. Let D be the sum of x^(n^2) where n runs over the positive integers prime to 2M. Then D lies in P and is annihilated by all T_p, with p not equal to 2 or M.

When M=3 I can show that the only elements of P annihilated by each T_p with p in {5,7,11,13,17,19} are 0 and D. (The proof is intricate, using a level 3 analog to the level 1 theory of Nicolas and Serre, together with a close analysis of P and the unexpected Hecke isomorphism of question 203755, "Two spaces attached to mod 2 level 9 modular forms...").

Can one provide similar finite lists of p for general M, and in particular for M=5? I'm not worried about redundancy. Presumably the theory of the Hecke algebra shows that such a list exists for each M.

Comment: I was imprecise in defining O as the "m-completion of HE". The m-completion in the usual sense, (HE)^, the inverse limit of the HE/(m^j) is a power series ring in infinitely many variables. Instead let M(m) be the subspace of M consisting of u annihilated by a power of m. Then (HE)^ acts on M(m), and O is the quotient of (HE)^ by the ideal of elements annihilating M(m).

Comment: One may ask analogous questions when ell> 3. But now M isn't closed under + and one works with (ell-1)/2 spaces M(w) with w even in [0,ell-3]. (M(w) is now the set of reductions of expansions of modular forms whose weight j is w mod (ell-1). Since for fixed n the mod ell reduction of n^(j-1) only depends on j mod (ell-1), the Hecke operators T_n are well defined at the characteristic ell level, and one gets a shallow Hecke algebra HE(w) acting on M(w).) But I haven't looked at this more general situation yet.

Comment: Can I suggest you make the question easier to read by taking use of MathJAX and linking the question you refer to?